# GSON from json file to object

Tags: java, android, json, mapping, gson

how can I parse an object that looks like this with GSON:

```
{ response: 
          { value1: 0, 
            value2: "string", 
            bigjsonObject: {
                 value1b: 0,
                 bigJSONArray: [...]
          }
 }
```

All of the examples in GSON have less mixed value types, and the docs mention something about how this can screw up GSON deserialization but don't elaborate and still suggest that GSON can map this to an object.

My current test using `gson.fromJSON(inputstream, myObject.class)` returns an object with null values, so it is not mapping them.

`myObject.class` contains an ArrayList of type `bigJSONArray`

```
public class myObject {

        private ArrayList<bigObjectModel> bigJSONArray;

        myObject(){};
}
```

my assumption is that my ArrayList object doesn't have the types it is looking for, or something. But I am misunderstanding how mapping should work in this case.

Comment: `gson.fromJSON(inputstream, myObject.class)` , do you want to see what myObject.class looks like?

Comment: @SunilMishra  it contains array lists of objects, I was hoping that GSON would just skip the key/value pairs that my object didn't have declared

Comment: Gson does skip the values you dont have declared. Please post you myObject class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to parse

```
{ response: 
      { value1: 0, 
        value2: "string", 
        bigjsonObject: {
             value1b: 0,
             bigJSONArray: [...]
      }
}
```

You need the container class to be

```
public class myObject {

    private int    value1;
    private String value2;
    private Foo    bigjsonObject;
}
```

Where the Class Foo is

```
public class Foo {

    private int value1b;
    private ArrayList<bigObjectModel> bigJSONArray
}
```

You may ommit any field and GSON will just skip it

Comment: this was very helpful, turned out I had to do a lot of maneuvering for custom serialization